# Run a PHP Function when User Clicks a Link Using the Post Method

Tags: php, function, post, submit

What would be the cleanest way to run the PHP code below but instead of $_GET, using $_POST instead?

```
<?php
function run_my_function() {
    echo 'I just ran a PHP function!';
}
if (isset($_GET['run'])) {
    run_my_function();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Hello there! <a href="?run">Run a PHP function.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NO*, you cannot send post request from anchor tag. you will have to use `<form>`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to do that , check this example

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    function run_my_function() {
            echo 'I just ran a PHP function!';
}
if (isset($_GET['run'])) {
    run_my_function();
}
}

?>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#run').click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                     url: '/',
                     type: 'POST',

                     success: function(response) {
                         alert('hiii')

                         return response;
                     }
                });
             });

    });
</script>

<body>
    <p>Hello there! <a id='run' href="javascript:;">Run a PHP function.</a></p>
</body>
```